# Vagrant - Changing the ssh password conection

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

Well, i am doing some tests with virtual machines with Vagrant, but now i am having problems changing the machine's default password which is "vagrant" when i try to connect throw ssh via terminal.

Here is the Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "192.168.0.21"
  config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
  config.ssh.password = '123'
  config.ssh.insert_key = true
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "wlan0", ip: "192.168.0.21" 
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "192.168.0.21"
    v.cpus = 1
    v.memory = 512
  end
end
```

You realize that i changed my password (config.ssh.password) to '123', but when i restart the machine (vagrant halt --> and vagrant up), this happens:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: root
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
root@127.0.0.1's password:
```

I don't know what to do...
I appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The configuration does not changes machine's password. It just changes the password used by Vagrant to authenticate via SSH with machine. [See more on docs.](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html)

If you want to change user password on machine, initialize machine with default password, and once you are connected you change it by SSH authenticated command line (or GUI, if configured on vagrant file).

Comment: I want to change the password used to authenticate via ssh, but i am changing the "config.ssh.password" and it's not working, the password keeps the default ("vagrant").I already gave "vagrant halt" and "vagrant up" and keep the same ssh password

Comment: as its mentioned, you need to go into the VM, run `passwd` so you can change your password then you can change the Vagrantfile with the same password you have updated